# JPA Criteria API - query childclass and filter for object within the childclass

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am building a web application with Spring Boot. This application contains the Employees and I am trying to filter them with the JPA Criteria API.

The problems:

- `Employee` contains a field `var workingModel: WorkingModel` which is a super class. I want to filter for the child class `PartTime`. How do I cast to this child class with the API?
- The child class `PartTime` contains a list of `PartTimePeriod`. I want to check whether there is a `PartTimePeriod` that matches the criteria. How do I do this?
- I want to relax the constraints of the filter criteria of `PartTimePeriod` so that if for example only `startTime` matches and `endTime` is off by 1 or 2 hours it also returns the `Employee`.

Here is the Code:

```java
@Entity(name = "Employee")
class Employee {
    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    var workingModel: WorkingModel

    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "working_model")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
open class WorkingModel (
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    var employee: Employee? = null,

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "working_model_id", nullable = false)
    private var id: Long = 0
)
```

```java
@Entity(name = "part_time")
class PartTime(
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    var partTimePeriods: MutableList<PartTimePeriod> = ArrayList()
) : WorkingModel()
```

**UPDATE:**

I have a somewhat complex query, where I want to filter the Employees by some fields and rank them accorinding to the best fit.

To filter for `PartTime` i wanted to make a subquery which looks like this:

```java
    private fun subQueryForPartTimePeriod(root: Root<Employee?>, builder: CriteriaBuilder, query: CriteriaQuery<*>, criteria: SearchCriteria): Predicate {
        val subquery: Subquery<PartTimePeriod> = query.subquery(PartTimePeriod::class.java)


        val workingModel = root.join<Employee, WorkingModel>("workingModel")
        val partTime = builder.treat(workingModel, PartTime::class.java)
        val partTimePeriods = partTime.join<PartTime, PartTimePeriod>("partTimePeriods")

        subquery.select(partTimePeriods)
        subquery.where(builder.equal(partTimePeriods.get<String>("day"), (criteria.value as PartTimePeriod).day),
            builder.equal(partTimePeriods.get<LocalTime>("startTime"), (criteria.value).startTime),
            builder.equal(partTimePeriods.get<LocalTime>("endTime"), (criteria.value).endTime))
       return builder.exists(subquery)
    }
```

This gives me the following error when trying to filter by `PartTime`:

```
unexpected token: where near line 1, column 782 [select distinct generatedAlias0 from com.jobstop.backend.model.employee.Employee as generatedAlias0 inner join generatedAlias0.jobInterestRegions as generatedAlias1 inner join generatedAlias0.workingModel as generatedAlias2 inner join generatedAlias0.workingModel as generatedAlias3 inner join generatedAlias3.partTimePeriods as generatedAlias4 inner join generatedAlias0.professions as generatedAlias5 where ( ( generatedAlias1.jobInterestRegion=:param0 ) or ( function('ST_Distance_Sphere', function('point', generatedAlias0.latitude, generatedAlias0.longitude), function('point', 46.70961D, 14.50697D))<generatedAlias1.distance ) ) and ( :param1 = true ) order by (case when generatedAlias5.umbrellaTerm=:param2 then 2 else 0 end+(case when exists (select generatedAlias4 from  where ( generatedAlias4.day=:param3 ) and ( generatedAlias4.startTime=:param4 ) and ( generatedAlias4.endTime=:param5 )) then 10 else 0 end+0)) desc]
```

Comment: is there something blocking you from using @MappedSuperclass ? https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: i would use it in your case and avoid the unnecesary "working_model" table in your schema